# What is this probability distribution where the failure probability is $p$ and is repeated $n$ times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a trial, the probability of failure is $p$. If the trial is repeated $n$ times, the probability of failure is $p^n$.
That is, if the trial is performed 2 times, the probability of failure is $p^2$; if performed 3 times the probability of failure is $p^3$.

I want to know, what is the probability distribution of the trials?

Edit: Well, I have two questions in mind.

1. What is the probability that there is a failure after $n$ trials? The answer is:

$1-(1-p)^n$

2. What is the probability that there is a success after $n$ trials? The answer is:

$1-p^n$

What are these distributions?

Comment: Are you asking for the probability distribution of the **number** of trials **it takes to see the first failure**?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have edited the question. Please see.

Comment: Your answer to (1) is incorrect. The probability there is a failure is $1$ minus the probability of no failures, so it should be $1-(1-p)^n$. Also, I still do not understand what you are asking for. The word "distribution" is reserved for random variables, and you are just talking about events. Events are not called distributions.

Comment: Well, see this, in terms of $n$, where $n=1,2,3,...$, the probability is $1-p^n$, what is this distribution in terms of n?

It is not a binomial distribution.